# apply withJavadocJar() and withSourcesJar() for all subProjects in multi-module build

Tags: gradle, kotlin

currently I have:

```
java {
    withJavadocJar()
    withSourcesJar()
}
```

in all build.gradle.kts files of modules in an multi-module build. With gradle and groovy I could just have this in the root gradle file - but I seem to not be able to do this with kotlin gradle files. Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Placing the following in the root `build.gradle.kts` file should work:

```
subprojects {
    apply<JavaPlugin>() // or: apply(plugin = "java")

    configure<JavaPluginExtension> {
        withSourcesJar()
        withJavadocJar()
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the Kotlin DSL loses some of its ease-of-use when cross-configuring projects. See the [Gradle Kotlin DSL Primer](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#sec:kotlin_cross_project_configuration) guide for more information.